# How to convert date and time from UTC to local time in R?

Tags: r, date, datetime, time, timezone

I have a dataframe (`vlinder`) like the following, whereby the date and the timestamp (in UTC) are in separate columns:

```
date      time.utc variable  
1/04/2020 0:00:00  12  
1/04/2020 0:05:00  54
```

In a first step, I combined the `date` and `time` variables into one column called `dateandtime` using the following code:

```
vlinder$dateandtime <- paste(vlinder$date, vlinder$time.utc)
```

which resulted in an extra column in dataframe `vlinder`:

```
date      time.utc variable  dateandtime
1/04/2020 0:00:00  12        1/04/2020 0:00:00
1/04/2020 0:05:00  54        1/04/2020 0:05:00
```

I want to convert the time of UTC into local time (which is CEST, so a time difference of 2 hours).

I tried using the following code, but I get something totally different.

```
vlinder$dateandtime <- as.POSIXct(vlinder$dateandtime, tz = "UTC")
vlinder$dateandtime.cest <- format(vlinder$dateandtime, tz = "Europe/Brussels", usetz = TRUE)
```

which results in:

```
date         time.utc variable   dateandtime   dateandtime.cest
1/04/2020    0:00:00  12         0001-04-20    0001-04-20 00:17:30 LMT
1/04/2020    0:05:00  54         0001-04-20    0001-04-20 00:17:30 LMT
```

How can I solve this?
Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default format of `as.POSIXct` expects an date ordered by Year-Month-Day. Therefore the date 01/04/2020 is translated into the 20th April of Year 1.

You just need to add your timeformat to `as.POSIXct`:

```
vlinder$dateandtime <- as.POSIXct(vlinder$dateandtime, tz = "UTC", format = "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")

format(vlinder$dateandtime, tz = "Europe/Brussels", usetz = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's a `lubridate` and `tidyverse` answer.  Some data tidying, data type changes, and then bam. Check `lubridate::OlsonNames()` for valid time zones (`tz`).  (I'm not positive I chose the correct `tz`.)

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

df <- read.table(header = TRUE, 
                 text = "date      time.utc variable 
                        1/04/2020 00:00:00  12  
                        1/04/2020 00:05:00  54")


df <- df %>%
  mutate(date = mdy(date),
         datetime_utc = as_datetime(paste(date, time.utc)),
         datetime_cest = as_datetime(datetime_utc, tz = 'Europe/Brussels'))
```

```
        date time.utc variable        datetime_utc       datetime_cest
1 2020-01-04 00:00:00       12 2020-01-04 00:00:00 2020-01-04 01:00:00
2 2020-01-04 00:05:00       54 2020-01-04 00:05:00 2020-01-04 01:05:00
```